# Same partition key's data distribution in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, distributed-system, database, nosql

From what I'm understanding, DynamoDB tries to put items with the same partition key into the same partition. My question is how does the hashing work when the partition is full and gets split into 2 different partitions?

For example, a table has a partition key `A`, and DynamoDB put all items with partition key `A` into the same partition `P`, then `P` is full, dynamo will split `P` into `P1` and `P2`, now a new item `I` with a partition key `A` is inserted by the client, How does dynamo decide which partition (i.e. `P1` and `P2`) to insert `I`?

Comment: I believe in such case sort key will be used along with primary key to identify partition

Answer (score 3):

> All items with the same partition key are stored together, and for composite partition keys, are ordered by the sort key value. DynamoDB splits partitions by sort key if the collection size grows bigger than 10 GB.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

So in that case they will use the sort key to decide in which partition the elements are stored.

However, I don't know how they deal with the case in which there is no sort key.

I also guess that the time to access a partition will not be constant anymore, because it will be needed to find the proper partition in logarithmic time respect to the number of partitions for this partition key. Since if you use the sort key with the partition key to compute a 'merged' hash key, you won't be able to keep the elements sorted (elements with contiguous sort keys would be in different partitions).

Answer (score 1):

Partition Key is used mainly to specify where to store physically the data, this is done using **consistent hashing function** to distribute your data into different partitions or physical storage. To read the value using partition key, it is going to hash it using the same hashing function to get the correct partition then fetch the data from that partition. While sort key is used to index that data inside each partition.

Partition keys should be designed in away that maintains **evenly** distribution of your workload instead of having some partitions fully overflown or loaded while having others idle.

You can read more about this here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html

https://cloudacademy.com/blog/dynamodb-replication-and-partitioning-part-4/

Comment: i read that "All items with the same partition key are stored together" in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/. This doesn't make sense to me. I believe the docs meant to say, "all items with the same partion identifier are stored together", where partition identifier = hash(partition key). Is this understanding correct? It confuses me because the sentence suggests multiple items (rows) can have same partition key, yet partition key must be unique..

Answer (score -3):

For what i understand, one table cannot have more than one item with same partition key (assume no sort key as part of primary key)

I tried to save same partition key into DynamoDB and it failed